# Efficiently filter large dataset by time and location window repeatedly, relative to each point

Tags: r, database

I have a data set consisting of about 55 million records, split across many CSVs. Each record contains a datetime, a latitude, and a longitude, representing a lightning event and the location at which it occurred. I need to add a field, wherein for each event I need to list the time in seconds since the last event that occurred within 5 nautical miles of the current one. The code I've written below works, technically, but I had to stop it after it spent more than an hour on the first CSV.

Though I wrote this in R, I am willing to make use of any language or tool that can accomplish my objective without requiring days or weeks to process the data set. I've attempted SQLite as well, but so far on that front I've only frustrated myself in trying to get it to do the math at all.

Also note, during this search some entries will return NA due to there not being any previous events that meet the criteria. This is fine; I want NA in that case.

A sample of the CSV data follows the code, and I've made a file containing one day's data available for testing at:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i02jl6bswq0zlel/2019.05.02.TL.csv?dl=1

(I'm using taxicab distances for now in the code below, and the `0.08335` and `0.0965` values approximate 5 nmi in lat/long values based on the average latitude of all recorded events. If there's a method that will do Pythagorean distances quickly then that would be wonderful.)

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)

#Get list of all relevant CSVs
fList = list.files(pattern = "*.TL.csv")

#Reads in the first CSV; haven't implemented looping through files yet 
t1 = read.csv(as.character(fList[1]), colClasses=c(DateTime="character"))
t1 = t1[order(t1$DateTime),]  #Sort by DateTime
rownames(t1) = NULL  #Reset index

#Used for filtering the current row out of the search
index = c(1:nrow(t1))

#Create empty column
t1$TimeGap = NA

for (i in 2:nrow(t1)) {
  temp = max(filter(t1, (DateTime <= t1$DateTime[i]) &
                        (Latitude >= t1$Latitude[i]-0.08335) &
                        (Latitude <= t1$Latitude[i]+0.08335) &
                        (Longitude >= t1$Longitude[i]-0.0965) &
                        (Longitude <= t1$Longitude[i]+0.0965) &
                        (index != i))$DateTime)
  t1$TimeGap[i] = as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(t1$DateTime[i],format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"),
                                      as.POSIXct(temp,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"),
                                      units="secs"))
}
```

**CSV data sample:**

```
"DateTime","Latitude","Longitude"
"2019-05-02 14:43:37.833",26.9517,-81.4851
"2019-05-02 14:43:37.857",26.9674,-81.4758
"2019-05-02 14:43:37.988",26.9802,-81.4698
"2019-05-02 14:45:41.512",27.0024,-81.4612
"2019-05-02 15:22:59.614",27.295,-81.1728
"2019-05-02 15:24:06.284",27.3444,-81.1213
"2019-05-02 15:24:51.607",27.3306,-81.146
"2019-05-02 15:26:52.130",27.5441,-81.1099
"2019-05-02 15:26:52.131",27.3214,-81.1758
"2019-05-02 15:26:52.131",27.3326,-81.1614
"2019-05-02 15:26:52.134",27.5396,-81.0952
"2019-05-02 15:26:52.134",27.5377,-81.1069
"2019-05-02 15:26:52.156",27.517,-81.1147
"2019-05-02 15:26:52.167",27.5377,-81.0962
"2019-05-02 15:28:59.356",27.5156,-81.1152
"2019-05-02 15:28:59.357",27.519,-81.1092
"2019-05-02 15:28:59.359",27.406,-81.174
"2019-05-02 15:28:59.362",27.4081,-81.1489
"2019-05-02 15:28:59.362",27.508,-81.1472
"2019-05-02 15:28:59.364",27.5183,-81.1497
"2019-05-02 15:28:59.417",27.5338,-81.1712
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.021",27.4052,-81.1956
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.027",27.4381,-81.1837
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.027",27.5141,-81.159
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.027",27.417,-81.1631
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.027",27.5439,-81.1326
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.048",27.4809,-81.1691
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.048",27.4666,-81.1561
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.048",27.4666,-81.1561
"2019-05-02 15:31:39.048",27.401,-81.1679
```

Comment: Yeah the only way I see forward is to use Rcpp and compile your own function for c++ to run the loop. anything over 100K rows in native R will run into memory issues.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a situation where the (relatively new) package [`disk.frame`](https://diskframe.com/) will excel. It is similar to the [`data.table`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/) but with mind on very large amounts of data. Without having used it, but with my knowledge from `data.table`, and assuming that all your data is in `file.path(getwd(), 'data')`, you could likely achieve your goal using something like

```
library(disk.frame)
# Setup from the ingesting Data vignette
if(interactive()) { 
  setup_disk.frame()
  # highly recommended, however it is pun into interactive() for CRAN because
  # change user options are not allowed on CRAN
  options(future.globals.maxSize = Inf)  
} else {
  setup_disk.frame(2)
}
# Import csv data from shared folder
disk.f <- csv_to_disk.frame(list.files(file.path(getwd(), 'data'), full.names = TRUE))
```

Once imported we should be able to do calculations in the standard `data.table` syntax

```
disk.f[, `:=`(LatitudeMax = Latitude + 0.08335,
              LatitudeMin = Latitude - 0.08335,
              LongitudeMax = Longitude + 0.0965, 
              LongitudeMin = Longitude - 0.0965,
              rowid = seq_len(.N),
              Datetime = as.POSIXct(Datetime, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"))]
# Perform selv join.. I hope I got the direction right here.
calc.disk.f <- 
  disk.f[disk.f[, .(Latitude.i = Latitude, 
                    Longitude.i = Longitute, 
                    Datetime.i = Datetime, 
                    rowid.i = rowid)], 
         on = .(Datetime >= Datetime.i,
                LongitudeMax >= Longitude.i,
                LongitudeMin <= Longitde.i, 
                LatitudeMax >= Latitude.i,
                LatitudeMin <= Latitude.i,
                rowid != rowid.i), 
         allow.cartesian = TRUE][, .(Timegap = difftime(Datetime, 
                                                        max(Datetime.i), 
                                                        units = 'secs')), 
                                 by = rowid]
# Merge result into original frame.
disk.f <- calc_disk_f[disk.f, on = rowid]
# clean up calc.disk.f
delete(calc.disk.f)

# Save result or change to a regular data.table/data.frame/tibble
## Not sure if this is in csv, fst or what format.
write_disk.frame(disk.f, outdir = file.path(getwd(), data, 'result.df'))
```

#### Disclaimer!

I have not been able to test the above code, so it is likely riddled with typos and possibly a wrong-sided join (Should my aggregation group by `rowid` or `rowid.i`? I might have turned it one way or the other), and a self-join that has not been tested in `disk.frame` (maybe creating a copy of the `disk.frame` is necessary). I might create a more reproducible example, but more likely this can be used as a starting point and give ground for a proper solution.

Note `disk.frame` similarly has a `dplyr` like interface, which could be used in case that the `data.table` self-join syntax doesn't work out.

## Update 1:

It seems that the `data.table` syntax for `disk.frame` is a partial wrapper into the `data.table` universe, as such the join I suggested does not work as expected. Using `foverlaps` is currently my second-option for a fast subsetting method.